# Identifying Triangles Program

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program in Java that identifies triangles (just for fun). Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sides[] = new int[3];
    for(int i = 0; i<sides.length; i++){
        if(i == 0){
            System.out.println("What is the measure of the first side?");
            Scanner side1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            sides[i] = side1.nextInt();
        }
        else if(i == 1){
            System.out.println("What is the measure of the second side?");
            Scanner side2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            sides[i] = side2.nextInt();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("What is the measure of the third side?");
            Scanner side3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            sides[i] = side3.nextInt();
        }
    }
    if(sides[1] == sides[2] && sides[2] == sides[3]){
        System.out.println("It's an equilateral triangle.");
    }
    else if(sides[1] == sides[2] || sides[1] == sides[3] || sides[2] == sides[3]){
        System.out.println("It's an isosceles triangle.");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("It's a scalene triangle.");
    }
}

}
```

However, when I run the code, it asks for all three sides, then it throws an exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:29)`. I input everything correctly, and there are no errors except that above exception. Do any of you know what's wrong, if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not 1. That should fix your code.

Comment: Array indices start at `0`. You should access elements in `sides` using `sides[0]`, `sides[1]`, and `sides[2]`

Answer (score 4):

Array indexes start with 0 and not 1. So, you need to modify the code like this at line 26:

```
 if(sides[0] == sides[1] && sides[1] == sides[2]){
        System.out.println("It's an equilateral triangle.");
    }
 else if(sides[0] == sides[1] || sides[1] == sides[2] || sides[0] == sides[2]){
        System.out.println("It's an isosceles triangle.");
    }
```

Comment: Oops. I forgot that part.